# Using VusJS and Axios, child component is not updating via databinding

Tags: mongoose, vue.js, axios

On the parent, under **mounted**, I have a function call:

```
this.getLevel()
```

Under **methods**, I have a Axios powered async call to my MongoDB:

```
  async getLevel () {
    console.log('trying...');
    const response = await ProjectService.getLevel(this.$route.params.id);
    this.diagramData = response.data.level.startNodeData;
   // console.log(response.data.level.startNodeData);
  },
```

Under **data** I have an empty array waiting for the update from the function callback:

```
data () {

  return {
    diagramData: [],
  }
},
```

The data is bound and sent to the component like this:

```
 <NodeViewer v-bind:model-data="diagramData"  v-on:changed-selection="changedSelection" ></NodeViewer>
```

Now, in the **child** (component) I have **Props** like this:

```
 props: ["modelData"],  // accept model data as a parameter
```

My question is why is it that if I add JSON directly into the **diagramData** the child updates as expected without issue, but when I update the diagramData using the async method in the mount, the child component does not update as expected? Should I not be mounting the async call? Should it be in another lifecycle hook like created?

Comment: is it the same if you use `this.$set(this, 'diagramData', response.data.level.startNodeData)` when updating the array ?

Comment: Yes, same issue. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Can you add a **deep** watcher to your child component (NodeViewer) that watches for changes to `modelData` to test your theory that `modelData` is indeed not updated? Just log it to console if changes occur.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  Can you show the definition of the child component and specify which is the parent?  I can't tell if `NodeViewer` is the parent or the child.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was as simple as converting the async callback with JSON.parse like this:

```
this.diagramData = JSON.parse(response.data.level.startNodeData);
```

Was sending a string and not an object. Hope this helps others :)